# counting table rows in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object-reference

I am counting table rows in MVC view.

The below code was counting from a linked table but has now stoped giving me the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Has anyone any idea as to why this would happen?

`@Model.Count(x => x.Device.VehicleReg != null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Device` is null and throws exception 
Try this:

```
@Model.Where(x=> x.Device != null).Count(x=> x.Device.VehicleReg)
```

Comment: How do I subtract another @Model.Count from the above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Model` is not null, probably `Device` is `null` that's why you get the "Object reference " error